# How to assign button values ​to an event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a MainButton object with a Button component. A component has a property (or what it is) On Click (). This property can have an object and a method that will be executed by pressing a button. I tried to set these values ​​in the inspector, but these values ​​are not saved in the prefab, because they are assigned from Assets, and not from Scene. How to assign this method and object through programming? Who didn't understood - I need to change properties (object, method) of the event "OnClick()" by the script.

Comment: Try to add more details, for example add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Unity.OnClick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) `UnityEvent`.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Make sure to attach these Buttons in the Inspector
    public Button m_YourFirstButton, m_YourSecondButton, m_YourThirdButton;

    void Start()
    {
        //Calls the TaskOnClick/TaskWithParameters/ButtonClicked method when you click the Button
        m_YourFirstButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
        m_YourSecondButton.onClick.AddListener(delegate {TaskWithParameters("Hello"); });
        m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonClicked(42));
        m_YourThirdButton.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick()
    {
        //Output this to console when Button1 or Button3 is clicked
        Debug.Log("You have clicked the button!");
    }

    void TaskWithParameters(string message)
    {
        //Output this to console when the Button2 is clicked
        Debug.Log(message);
    }

    void ButtonClicked(int buttonNo)
    {
        //Output this to console when the Button3 is clicked
        Debug.Log("Button clicked = " + buttonNo);
    }
}
```